# Can't Turn Bluetooth On

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth, windows-10

When I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 it was working great, but then I accidentally booted to windows 10, and then it stopped working. I was wondering if there was a way to reset the adapter or device. I don't fully understand what my options are.

It says bluetooth is turned off, and when I toggle it, the toggle turns green but bluetooth remains "bluetooth is turned off". When I unplug it it says "no bluetooth found". So I assume its detecting it fine.

My device: [Bluetooth 5.0 Dongle Techkey](https://www.mytechkey.com/pages/driver) works great on windows 10, and was working fine on Ubuntu 20.04.

I read possibly removing CMOS battery from motherboard might help?

I found this answer(I feel like it is the closest solution, but I can't figure it out), but I can't completely follow it: [Bluetooth Pairing on Dual Boot of Windows & Linux Mint/Ubuntu - Stop having to Pair Devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p/255510#255510)

I tried:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Nothing changed.

```
lsusb (with device plugged in and then again not plugged in)
```

revealed

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 Hub
```

Comment: I've got the same problem and I'm beginning to think that there is no compatible linux driver for the BT chip on the Techkey dongle. While searching on the Realtek website for Bluetooth 5.0 chipsets, I only found the RTL8762C, which doesn't seem to work on any current linux distribution. This is total guessswork, but it seems as if Ubuntu identified the chipset on the Techkey dongle as the RTL8761a, which is an older Bluetooth 4.0 chipset.

Comment: I have same problem with my C-TECH BTD-01 adaptor with RTL8761B chipset (detected as 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio). The system will find it but bluetooth cannot be turned on and paired with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have already had a lot of trouble with the Bluetooth adapter on my Dell laptop. Actually, I've been having these problems ever since I started using my Bluetooth headphone together with this laptop. It sort of works when it feels like doing, kind of buggy.
However, this is a solution that has helped me a lot.

If Bluetooth remains off, no matter what you try, open terminal and enter this command to force *bluetooth.service* to turn on:

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

You can also try to stop *bluetooth.service* and switch it back on a while afterwards:

```
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

It has been working for me so far. I hope that helps you too.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I tried what you suggested and it doesn't work. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Have you tried installing "stacer"? It works perfectly as a GUI-ish way of dealing with services, instead of using "sudo systemctl" for enabling, disabling and testing things like this out. Perhaps it can facilitate things with bluetooth for you. Try "sudo apt install stacer" and test it out.

Comment: Hey stacer is sweet thanks, but it didn't work for turning on bluetooth. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unfortunately stopping and restarting the Bluetooth service doesn't solve my problem. I have noticed that the Techkey stick does showan empty MAC address when running Ubuntu. My guess is that this particular Bluetooth 5 USB dongle just doesn't work with Linux.